# Creating an REST API Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

The first thing that I would like to say is that I have no previous experience with python and any framework python related. However, I have programming experience.

So, I want to create a REST API using python with frameworks `django` and `djangorestframework`. I have managed to create the database (using postgresql) and also managed to create the initial migration. However, I believe that that was the easiest part and I have some questions about  the thing that I'm about to implement:

1. First I want to create an authentication system. I saw that `djangorestframework` it's able to manage authentication by itself but I was not able to make it run. Can you please guide me to some good tutorials/provide code samples and briefly explain?
2. After initial migration, I saw that `django` created some tables for authentication and session management by itself (auth_user, auth_user_groups, etc). Is there any way to use my own model for user? Also, i do believe that I wont need all the features that django offerrs (e.g auth_user_groups). Its there any way to remove those unwanted functionalities?
3. I was able to create an API endpoint (by following a tutorial) that returns some data (based on a model, a serializer and a view created by me). However, as I want to create more API endpoints I have also to create a serializer and view for each model of mine (which might take a while). Is there any way to create a generic serializer and a generic view method so I don't need to write a specific serializer and a view method (e.g I would like to GET models by /api/books/book/:id, where book its just a placeholder for any model)?

P.S. If this post lacks any informations please let me know in a comment and I will edit this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let's see:

1. Documentation is your best friend. This is especially true in case of Django which has great [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/). Generally, there are three ways to use authentication in Django:

   - Default User class (`django.contrib.auth.user.models`) just works out of the box.
   - You can extend it by creating other model (like Profile) and linking it via `OneToOneField`.
   - Alternatively, you can provide your own User class via subclassing (usually AbstractBaseUser) and registering it in Django's settings.
   - Finally, you can write completely custom backend.

   For customization guide consult this [article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/).
2. For the first part of the question see paragraph above. Regarding removing  user groups: its probably possible (though I've never tried it), but I don't see much point. It has practically no overhead whatsoever while providing some useful stuff like staff/admin groups for Django's admin panel.
3. Absolutely there is a generic solution. Just use *generic API views*. Again, I'm linking [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#destroyapiview). In short, you want to use subclasses of `GenericAPIView` class.
   For instance, let's say to want to list User objects under `/users/` path:

   ```
   url(r'^/users/', ListCreateAPIView.as_view(queryset=User.objects.all(), serializer_class=UserSerializer), name='user-list')
   ```

   For your particular example you would use `RetrieveAPIView`. If you want to look it up with `pk` you don't even have to configure it.